# 'xdg-open: unexpectted argument' - no argument in C# under debian 9 using mono

Tags: c#, tcp, compiler-errors, debian, monodevelop

I have a Problem using Linux (Debian 9). I want to use a Socket programmed with C# to communicate with another operating system via TCP/IP and I do not understand the error message with xdg-open.
Maybe someone has an idea?

I can't include a picture directly of the problem until I get 10 reputations. So here is the text of the command-window and the cs-code.

```
tarkan@debian:~$ csc Linux_Speech.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

tarkan@debian:~$ mono Linux_Speec.exe
Cannot open assembly 'Linux_Speec.exe': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
tarkan@debian:~$ mono Linux_Speech.exe
Trying to connect
Waiting for a connection... Connected!
1033
Received:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
xdg-open: unexpected argument '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              '
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.

Unhandled Exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00102] in <9c6e2cb7ddd8473fa420642ddcf7ce48>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00032] in <9c6e2cb7ddd8473fa420642ddcf7ce48>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at MyTcpListener.Main () [0x00143] in <8eb789c8f4ac4092aad9457c717ff113>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00102] in <9c6e2cb7ddd8473fa420642ddcf7ce48>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00032] in <9c6e2cb7ddd8473fa420642ddcf7ce48>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at MyTcpListener.Main () [0x00143] in <8eb789c8f4ac4092aad9457c717ff113>:0



***The cs-code***

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; //Linux
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq; //Linux
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
//using System.Speech.Synthesis; //Windows
using System.Threading;


class MyTcpListener
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Initialize server
            Int32 port = 2003;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.30");
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            // Start the "listen"-process
            // The server waits until a client wants to communicate
            server.Start();
            // Receive buffer
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[512];
            String data = null;
            // "listening"-loop
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
                // Client is accepted and the connection is established
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                data = null;
                // Provides the underlaying data stream for network access
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                int i;
                // Send and receive loop
                while ((i = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    Byte[] texttospeech = new Byte[512];
                    Byte[] languageID = new Byte[10];


                    // Language-ID:
                    // Copy the transmitted language-ID into a new array
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 30, languageID, 0, 2);
                    // Exchange of the two Bytes
                    Array.Reverse(languageID, 0, 2);
                    // Conversion of data types
                    uint ID = BitConverter.ToUInt16(languageID, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine(ID);
                    // The text-to-speech part of the received telegram is
                    // filtered out by copying the content into an new array.
                    Array.Copy(buffer, buffer[70], texttospeech,
                    texttospeech.GetLowerBound(0), 480);
                    // Translation of the received data into an ASCII-string
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(texttospeech, 0,
                    i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                    // Text-to-speech (Linux):
                    Process process = new Process();
                    String modified = data.Insert(0, "\"");
                    String final = modified.Insert(479, "\"");
                    // Choice of the language with the help of the received
                    // language-ID
                    if (ID == 1033) // English (default language)
                    {
                        process.StartInfo.FileName = "espeak";
                        process.StartInfo.Arguments = final;
                        process.Start();
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                    else if (ID == 1031) //German
                    {
                        process.StartInfo.FileName = "espeak";
                        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v de " + final;
                        process.Start();
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                    else if (ID == 1036) // French
                    {
                        process.StartInfo.FileName = "espeak";
                        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v fr " + final;

                        process.Start();
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error in Language-ID!\n");
                        System.Console.ReadKey();
                        return;
                    }
                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send an answer (here: Answer = received data)
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                }
                // Terminate connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop the "listen"-process
            server.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }


}
```

Comment: Do no link images. And probably it is just text, so copy and past direct in the question: easy to googling to find the solution (hopefully in this page), and also for us to write the answer. And links to external site may change, making this page useless.

Comment: I can't until I got 10 reputations because I'm new.

Comment: But it is a command line interface, so you can copy and paste the content of that window

Comment: Okey I did as you told me. Thank you for your advice

Comment: It seems the error is in Linux_Speech, no idea the cause, maybe it is from a configuration file (unfortunately such program doesn't seem to provide good diagnostic). For me, it seems xdg-open got a wrong parameter (a `'` instead of a filename). but it is difficult to know.

Comment: If you reveal the code in `Linux_Speech.cs`, probably it only takes a few minutes to tell why.

Comment: I included the code:)